# How to read a file into a hashmap that has a list as the value?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an assignment for my data structures class where we are required to store different subjects as the keys and teachers as the data using a built in data structure using map however its not possible to have duplicate keys so I have to store the values as a list. The data has to be read as a file. At first I mistakenly did the assignment by reading in the file and storing the students as keys but am unsure how i would do it in this case. Here is the function i used to read the file into a hashmap:

```
public static Map<String, String> getteachers(){

        Map<String, String> teachers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        BufferedReader buffer = null;

        try{
            File file = new File(filePath1);
            buffer = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file) );
            String line = null;

            while ( (line = buffer.readLine()) != null ){

                String[] parts = line.split(", ");
                String teacher = parts[0].trim();
                String subject = parts[1].trim();

                if( !subject.equals("") && !teacher.equals("") )
                    teachers.put(teacher, subject);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(buffer != null){
                try { 
                    buffer.close(); 
                }catch(Exception e){};
            }
        }        
        return teachers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     public static Map<String, List<String>> getTeachers(String filePath1) {
        Map<String, List<String>> teachers = new HashMap<>();
        BufferedReader buffer = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath1);
            buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.split(", ");
                String teacher = parts[0].trim();
                String subject = parts[1].trim();

                if (!subject.equals("") && !teacher.equals("")) {
                    if (!teachers.containsKey(teacher)) {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add(subject);
                        teachers.put(teacher, list);
                    } else {
                        teachers.get(teacher).add(subject);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (buffer != null) {
                try {
                    buffer.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return teachers;
    }
```